# Fetching JSON from SQL when a column is empty

Tags: json, sql-server, json-query, for-json

I have a table in SQL Server to keep all of the users app reviews.
When the user reviews the app with 4 or 5 stars I recieve JSON like this one

```
{
    "Calificacion": 5,
    "Cuestionario": "",
    "Comentarios": "",
    "Application": "APLIC004"
}
```

and when te user gives us a 3 stars or lower review, FrontEnd sends me JSON like this one

```
{
  "Calificacion": 0,
  "Cuestionario": [
    {
      "Order": 1,
      "Question": "string",
      "Answer": true
    }
    {
      "Order": 2,
      "Question": "string",
      "Answer": true
    }
    {
      "Order": 3,
      "Question": "string",
      "Answer": true
    }
    {
      "Order": 4,
      "Question": "string",
      "Answer": true
    }
  ],
  "Comentarios": "string",
  "Application": "string"
}
```

the problem is that when I try to query the most recent record from a user, I get this message when the recent record has no data for the column *Cuestionario*

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 114 JSON text is not properly
> formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0.

The query I'm using to fetch the data is the following

```
select TOP 1
  UserId,
  Fecha,
  Calificacion,
  JSON_QUERY(Cuestionario) Cuestionario,
  Comentarios,
  [Application]
from AppScores
where UserId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
order by Fecha desc
for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Comment: An empty string `''` is not valid JSON. You should instead use `NULL` or `'[]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're encountering occurs because SQL Server expects the value in the Cuestionario column to be a well-formatted JSON object, but you're getting an empty string when the rating is 4 or 5 stars.

```
CREATE TABLE AppScores (
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Fecha DATETIME,
    Calificacion INT,
    Cuestionario NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Comentarios NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Application] NVARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO AppScores (UserId, Fecha, Calificacion, Cuestionario, Comentarios, [Application])
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', GETDATE(), 5, '', '', 'APLIC004');

INSERT INTO AppScores (UserId, Fecha, Calificacion, Cuestionario, Comentarios, [Application])
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 3, '[
        {
          "Order": 1,
          "Question": "string",
          "Answer": true
        },
        {
          "Order": 2,
          "Question": "string",
          "Answer": true
        },
        {
          "Order": 3,
          "Question": "string",
          "Answer": true
        },
        {
          "Order": 4,
          "Question": "string",
          "Answer": true
        }
      ]', 'string', 'string');
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT TOP 1
       UserId,
       Fecha,
       Calificacion,
       JSON_QUERY(CASE
                     WHEN LEN(Cuestionario) = 0 THEN '[]'
                     ELSE Cuestionario
                  END) AS Cuestionario,
       Comentarios,
       [Application]
FROM AppScores
WHERE UserId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
ORDER BY Fecha DESC
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

| JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B |
| --- |
| {"UserId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Fecha":"2023-08-14T20:52:25.167","Calificacion":5,"Cuestionario":[],"Comentarios":"","Application":"APLIC004"} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CdOVVmBN)

Comment: `ISJSON` is probably a more reliable indicator for valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON_QUERY` with a single parameter basically tells the compiler "this is definitely valid JSON, do not escape it". But `''` is not valid JSON, nor is `'.'`. You should really use `NULL` or `'[]'` for empty values.

You can use the `ISJSON` function in a `CASE` or `IIF` to verify if the value is actually valid JSON.

```sql
JSON_QUERY(
  IIF(ISJSON(Cuestionario) = 1, Cuestionario, N'[]')
) AS Cuestionario
```